# How to implement an authorization system based on session variables?

Tags: php, symfony, silex, symfony-2.5, symfony-security

I am trying to migrate my application from Silex to Symfony.

I am using the Silex `before(...)` method to register methods to get executed before the action itself is been exectuted to check if some session variables are set.
I can do similar with the event listener in Symfony, but the controllers needs different before methods for contained action methods.

At the moment it looks like the following with Silex:

```
$controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
$controllers->before($this->guard('user'));

$controllers->get('/switch/{gameId}', $this->action('switch'))
    ->bind('game:switch')
    ->value('gameId', 0)
    ->assert('gameId', '\d+');
$controllers->match('/register', $this->action('register'))
    ->before($this->guard('player'))
    ->bind('game:register');

return $controllers;
```

A fully authenticated user can access some controller actions if he selects a container object before. So finally the guard methods are a kind of access control.
If the user accesses the actions without selecting the object, I want to redirect the user to the selection or similar.

<strike>One idea would be to implement it as roles and grant roles temporarily during the session.

I can combine it with a custom controller called by **access_denied_url** or the better way to implement an own **access_denied_handler** to handle Access denied by the access control handler.

But</strike> it seems that there is no possibility to store roles just temporar while the user is logged in.

Another idea is to use the **[allow_if](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-by-an-expression)** expression under access_control, but there is again the point, how do I react if there is an exception (access denied, how to implement an Access Denied Handler)?

How would you implement such a system?
Thanks for any hints in advice!

Comment: Isn't Silex built with Symfony?

Comment: It takes some parts of Symfony correct, but it is a Micro framework. As far as I know you can't copy just all files over and it works. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: What I mean is that you're replacing the Silex framework with another (custom?) framework (presumably) built with Symfony. So your question really is how to implement something that Silex handled in a Symfony-esque way? It's also a good idea to show examples of what you're trying to replicate.

Comment: I have added a small code snippet. I just want to transfer the `$this->guard('...')` calls to Symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I implemented the [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) solution to have something working and an interface which defines some methods to handle the different types of checking:

```
interface GameGuardController
{
    // returns the controller level of check
    public function getControllerLevel();

    // returns an array to override level for actions
    public function getMethodLevel();
}
```

Using the *RouterInterface*'s match `method` I get the route data and can extract the action name from the controller to access overriding method levels.